# Ajuda com criação de um algoritmo em arquivo.c

Tags: arquivo, concatenação-de-string

Olá estou com dificuldades em desenvolver um algoritmo que leia um arquivo.txt, faça a correção do texto e crie o resultado
em outro arquivo de saida. O processo de leitura deverá ocorrer linha por linha, porém o arquivo de entrada possui
o seguinte erro de sintaxe. O arquivo de entrada possui um problema em que diversas linhas são strings repetidas da 
linha anterior, diferenciando de apenas um caractere. O algoritmo deverá ter uma função que faça a comparação entre as duas
strings devolver 0 se forem iguais e o 1 se um caractere for diferente. Se mais caracteres forem diferentes, retorne a quantidade de caracteres diferentes entre elas.

t

te

tes

test

teste

saida: "teste"

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// cada linha não deverá ter mais que 1000 caractere//


int Comparar(char *s1, char *s2) {

    int i, j;

    while (*s1) 
        s1++;

    while (*s2) {
        *s1 = *s2;
         s2++;
         s1++;

    }
    *s1 = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char Linha[1000]

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo \n");
           return 1;

    }
    while (fgets(Linha, 1000, arquivo) != NULL)
        printf("%s", arquivo);
        fclose(

  if (argc != 3) 
{
    printf("\nExecute o programa da forma:\n");

    return 0;

  }
```

Comment: Me parece que você não colou seu código completa e corretamente.

Answer (score -1):

Irei refazer a função hoje para tentar mostrar como seria. Basicamente preciso de uma função que corrija essa sintaxe de strings. Ele não completa a frase, apenas quebra ela em várias linhas. Depois ao realizar essa correção, salvar em um "arquivo.txt", que seria de saída. Se ler o arquivo com a função fgets e passar como um dos parâmetros 500, que seria o numero de caractere, já faria essa leitura linha após linha e definiria apenas o (EOF) como delimitador. Correto? Essa minha função acho que dará para tratar esse erro de sintaxe.

B

Br

Bra

Bras

Brasi

Brasil

```
char* Comparar(char *s1, char *s2) {
int i, j;

for (i = 0; s1 != '\0'; ++i); {

   for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++i) {
      s1 = s2[j];
```

}
     s1 = '\0';
     return s1;
}